# What is the correct regex pattern for this?

Tags: java, regex

I was solving this question from Hackerrank

https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/find-google/challenges/find-google/problem

and came up with this pattern
"^[gG][o0O()\[\]{}][o0O()\[\]{}][gG][lLI][eE3]"
But this is giving wrong answer for test case g()()GI3. Can anyone tell me the error? Also tell me if there is more efficient expression for this.

```
    import java.util.regex.*;
    import java.io.*;
    import java.util.*;
    class Main {

public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String str = s.next();
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^[gG][o0O()\\[\\]{}][o0O()\\[\\]{}][gG][lLI][eE3]",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
    if(matcher.matches())
    System.out.println("YES");
    else System.out.println("NO");
}}
```

Comment: `[...]` character class can match only *one* symbol from specified range, so `[()]` doesn't represent `()` *sequence* but single `(` OR `)`. Same for `{}` (which probably should be `<>`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with the current regex is that `[]`, `()` and `<>` are put inside a character class that matches a single char inside it, but `()`, `<>` and `[]` char *sequences* consist of 2 chars.

You need to use a grouping construct with an alternation operator here to match `o`s.

You may use this pattern with `Pattern.matches()`:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[gG](?:[oO0]|\(\)|\[]|<>){2}[gG][LlI][eE3]");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ef8QSR/4)

**Details**

- `[gG]` - `g` or `G`
- `(?:[oO0]|\(\)|\[]|<>){2}` - two occurrences of

  - `[o0]` - `o`, `O` or `0`
  - `|` - or
  - `\(\)` - a `()` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `\[]` - a `[]` substring
  - `|` - or
  - `<>` - a `<>` substring
- `[gG]` - `g` or `G`
- `[LlI]` - `l`, `L` or `I`
- `[eE3]` - `e`, `E` or `3`.

Comment: it is giving error in java   prog.java:10: error: illegal escape character. Also why have you used ?:

Comment: @abhineetagarwal Use ``\\`` instead of ``\``.

Comment: why are ?: used. Also why do we need \\ before ( and ) but not before [ and ] in   "[gG](?:[oO0]|\\(\\)|\\[]|<>){2}[gG][LlI][eE3]"

Comment: @abhineetagarwal `?:` is non capturing group. '\\' is used to escape character which have special meaning it regex

Comment: @abhineetagarwal about `(?:...)` read [What is a non-capturing group? What does (?:) do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471).

Comment: Oh. I understand. But do we need delimiter before ( and ) and not for [and ]

Comment: Thank you @Pshemo. I changed the pattern to "[gG](?:[oO0]|\\(\\)|<>|\\[]){2}[gG][lLI][eE3]" .  But  in hackerrank, the test case "google " is failing as my code is giving answer as true. But the expected output is false. Does an extra space at the end of the test case "google " affect the answer?

Comment: @abhineetagarwal "why do we need \\ before ( and ) but not before [ and ]" but we do need \\ before `[`. We don't need it before `]`. Rationale is that if `]` doesn't have unescaped `[` and unclosed before it, regex engine cant match see `]` as ending of character class. In case of `)` similar rationale could be used but it would be more error-prone for programmers who write regex since groups `(..)` - especially nested - are used more often than `[]` so letting unescaped `)` would make regex harder to read. Also `)` is part of more regex mechanisms like `(?=..)`.

Comment: "the test case "google" is failing as my code is giving answer as true. But the expected output is false" either you are misreading something or it is bug in question. If we take a look at first example of input/expected output at https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/find-google/challenges/find-google/problem we see there `Sample Input 0 google` `Sample Output 0 True`. OR maybe it is case sensitive and it expects `True` not `true`.

Comment: does an extra space at the end of the input "google " affects the output?

Comment: @abhineetagarwal Yes, space is also a character so regex treats is as such. Try to apply regex on result of `string.trim()` if you don't want regex to handle spaces at start or end.

Comment: Yup. The whitespace was giving the error. I just applied a condition to compare trimmed and original string. Thanks @Pshemo.

Comment: @abhineetagarwal If you want to allow any amount of leading/trailing whitespace chars in your strings, add `\s*` at the start and end: `"\\s*[gG](?:[oO0]|\(\)|\[]|<>){2}[gG][LlI][eE3]\\s*"`. Non-capturing group is preferred when the text the group matches is not used later, as in this case.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use this**

You do not need to add both uppercase and lowercase of a letter when you use `case insensitive` flag.

```
g(?:o|0|<>|\[]){2}g[li][e3]
```

- `g` - Matches `g` or `G` ( as case insensitive flag is on )
- `(?:o|0|<>|\[])` - Matches `o` or `0` or `<>` or `[]`.
- `[li]` - Matches `L` or `l` or `I` or `i`.
- `[e3]` - Matches `e` or `E` or `3`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QtCD9P/4/)

Comment: `(o|0|<>|\[])(o|0|<>|\[])` can be rewritten as `(o|0|<>|\[]){2}` which IMO better shows intend on this regex (not to mention that it would be easier to maintain when you realize that you also need to handle `()`).

Answer (score 0):

I propose you this version of the regex string along with the code:

```
String string = bufferedReader.readLine();
String regex = "^[gG]([o0O]|\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}|\\<\\>){2}[gG][lLI][eE3]";        
String result = Pattern.matches(regex, string) ? "True" : "False";
System.out.println(result);
```

Since it's a "one shot" search you can use the static method "matches" of the Pattern class. That is, desume the result directly from a one-time match against your regex.

The regex is mostly the same as the one you devised, but some points are worth noting.

It is dangerous (if not erroneous) using case insensitivity when your regex tries to pick up letters of differente case. If you want to do the matching the classic way, avoid using the flag of case insensitivity. (in this particular case it would match a "google" written with a lower case "i" in place of a "L", which would lead to false positives).

Since there is only one way to express the "o", it is better to group its definition in a single sub-expression and then use the quantifier " {2} " to say that you exactly want two instances of that subexpression to match.

You want to find two occurrences of EITHER

- either a lower/upper case "o"
- a zero
- a *pair* of normal/square/curly/angular parentheses

Last but not least, if you are looking for simple, square, curly or angular braces, you *must* escape them because those are special characters in a regexp. Moreover, you must escape them the java way, using a double blackslash.

Here is the full code:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

       String string = bufferedReader.readLine();
       String regex = "^[gG]([o0O]|\\(\\)|\\[\\]|\\{\\}|\\<\\>){2}[gG][lLI][eE3]";        
       String result = Pattern.matches(regex, string) ? "True" : "False";
       System.out.println(result);

       bufferedReader.close();
}
```

It prints "True" when fed with the input "g()()GI3"